# RxAndroid interval API call. Is there a better way?

Tags: android, rx-android

Am doing a weather API call every 3secs and append the result to a textView using showWeather("weather") but I am sure there is a better way to do it. Am not sure why I need create Class Func1 but did because map required it. Also is there a way to shorten observer? I don't use lamda unfortunately. Any suggestions?

```
            Observer myObserver = new Observer<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String value) {
                    showWeather(value);
                }
            };

            class Func1<T, T1> implements io.reactivex.functions.Function<Long, String > {
                @Override
                public String apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return getJSON("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1",300);
                }
            }

            Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .map(new Func1<Long, Observable<String>>() {
                    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(myObserver);
```

I tried :

```
Observable
          .interval(3, SECONDS)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
              @Override
              public String call() throws Exception {
                  return getJSON("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1", 300);
              }
           })
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(myObserver)
```

But I get :

03-07 21:47:25.982 21181-21181/com.alex.rxandroidexamples E/imerExampleFragment$1$1: null
                                                                                     android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                         at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)

Also how do I unsubscribe onPause or onPause?

Comment: What makes you say you think there is a better way? This is a pretty straightforward use of `interval`.

Comment: am using Func1 because as I see it interval shoots doubles and I need something like map to pass the string on observer. Which seems inconvenient. I tried   Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Comment: Well of course you need `Func1`, the count from interval is not the item of interest. But what you have is exactly the intended pattern of using `map` to transform the input to a new output. So again, what do you think is not ideal about this?

Comment: Well am noobie in RX but can you see the edited question. I was wondering if something like this might be possible but I get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the best way to do this is :

```
private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

Observable fetchWeatherInterval = Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .map(new Function<Long, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                return getWeather("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?", "London,uk", "b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1");
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observer displayWeatherInterval = new Observer<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.e("Throwable ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        disposables.add(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String value) {
        textViewWeatherInterval.append(value);
    }
};

buttonFetchIntervalWeather.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fetchWeatherInterval.subscribe(displayWeatherInterval);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what about if error happens on network call? Is interval still running?

Comment: No, it will cut the flow. You can read more here : https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/